# PHP: Insufficient access when modify LDAP

Tags: php, ldap

This code can get me the correct thumbnail photo (got 1 result):

```
<?php
$ldap_username = "admin@domain.com.my";
$ldap_password = "password";
$domainname = "dc=domain,dc=com,dc=my";

$conn = ldap_connect("ldap://x.x.x.x:x/");
ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
$rs = ldap_bind($conn, $ldap_username , $ldap_password);

$search = "(&(objectCategory=person)(samaccountname=coisox))";
$rs = ldap_search($conn, $domainname, $search);
$ent = ldap_get_entries($conn, $rs);

for ($i = 0; $i < $ent["count"]; $i++) {
    echo "<br><b>Common Name: </b>" .   $ent[$i]["cn"][0];
    echo "<br><b>DN: </b>" .            $ent[$i]["dn"];
    echo "<br><b>Photo base64: </b>". (isset($ent[$i]["thumbnailphoto"]) && isset($ent[$i]["thumbnailphoto"][0])?base64_encode($ent[$i]["thumbnailphoto"][0]):'Photo not set');
}

ldap_close($conn);
?>
```

Then I try to modify the thumbnail by:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $ent["count"]; $i++) {
    $newdata = array();
    $newdata["thumbnailphoto"][0]='vvvvvv';

    if(!ldap_modify($conn, $ent[$i]["dn"], $newdata)){
        $enum = ldap_errno($conn);
        $msg = ldap_err2str($enum);
        echo "Photo change Failed for {$dn}.<br> {$msg}";
    }
    else{               
        echo "Photo Updated";
    }
}
```

And I got this error:

```
Warning: ldap_modify(): Modify: Insufficient access
```

I think my account has sufficient privilege to modify because  I also install [CJWDEV AD Photo Edit](http://www.cjwdev.com/Software/ADPhotoEdit/Info.html), and the only info that tools require from me in order to successfully query and upload new photo is domain, username, password. That tools didn't ask for specific CN or OU. So there must be some generic codes to makes this works.

One more thing, I tried to run this code in (in case this matter):

1. localhost
2. non https
3. https

#### Variations I've tried:

**Variation 1:**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $ent["count"]; $i++) {
    $newdata["thumbnailphoto"][0] = array();
    $newdata["thumbnailphoto"][0] ='vvvvvv';

    if(!ldap_modify($conn, $ent[$i]["dn"], $newdata)){
       ...same...
    }
}
```

**Variation 2:**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $ent["count"]; $i++) {
    $newdata["thumbnailphoto"][0] = array();

    if(!ldap_modify($conn, $ent[$i]["dn"], $newdata)){
       ...same...
    }
}
```

**Variation 3:**

```
$userdata["thumbnailphoto"] = array();
$userdata["thumbnailphoto"][0] = 'vvvvvv';
```

**Variation 4:**

```
$userdata = array();
$userdata["thumbnailphoto"] = array();
$userdata["thumbnailphoto"][0] = 'vvvvvv';
```

**Variation 5:**

```
$userdata = array();
$userdata["thumbnailphoto"] = array();
$userdata["thumbnailphoto"]["0"] = 'vvvvvv';
```

**Variation 6:**

```
$userdata = array();
$userdata["thumbnailphoto"] = array();
$userdata["thumbnailphoto"][] = 'vvvvvv';
```

**Variation 7 - Warning: ldap_modify(): Modify: No such object:**

```
$dn = $ent[$i]["dn"];
$userdata["thumbnailphoto"][0] = array();

//even I remove below line, same result
$userdata["thumbnailphoto"][0] = base64_decode('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');

ldap_modify($conn, "uid=$ldap_username,$dn", $userdata);
```

**Variation 8 - ldap_add(): Add: Object class violation:**

```
Using Variation 7, I change ldap_modify() to ldap_add()
```

Comment: When you read use $ent[$i]["thumbnailphoto"],  but you use   $ent[$i]["dn"] to write.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand. Means I should put the same $ent[$i]["thumbnailphoto"]? Like if(!ldap_modify($conn, $ent[$i]["thumbnailphoto"], 'vvvvvv'))?

Comment: No, you are ok. You must send the dn. Maybe you could try with variation2, but using index "thumbnailPhoto" with capital P. I will check an old code, I did the same and worked.

Comment: Sorry @Mate, when you got time, kindly check ur old code. I'm still stucks. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: So, ldap_modify($conn, "uid=coisox," . $ent[$i]["dn"] , $newdata) wiith vartiation 2... maybe $ent[$i]["uid"]   is "coisox"

Comment: Avoid to override your $rs after ldap_bind

Comment: Still no luck sir. Here is the cutoff version of "echo '<pre>', var_dump($ent[$i]), '</pre>'" incase it might help. I modify the data due to confidential. https://www.dropbox.com/s/coejdgofsnndtkr/adUploadPhoto%20AD%20Structure%20Ori.txt?dl=0

Comment: check Variation 7 , ldap_modify($conn, "uid=coisox," . $ent[$i]["dn"] , $newdata)  or maybe $ent[$i]["uid"] instead of 'coisox'  , You have your admin credentials in $ldap_username